# Resize Only Hitted Objects

Tags: java, arraylist

Hey how Can i make that only the hitted object is resized now it resizes all the bubbles in the arrays, i tried it in the else method but i dont seems to work propperly

```
void checkHitArrowWithBubbles() {
    for (int j = 0; j< bubblesArray.size(); j++) {
      for (int i = 0; i< arrowArray.size(); i++) {

        if (bubblesArray.get(j).checkHitArrow(arrowArray.get(i)))
        {
          println("BUBBLE IS HIT");

          arrowArray.remove(i);

          timesHit+=1;
          numberOfBubble*=2;
          scorePlayer+=5;

          bubbleWidth = bubble.width/2;
          bubbleHeight = bubble.height/2;
          bubble.resize(bubbleWidth, bubbleHeight);
          for ( int k = 0; k < numberOfBubble; k++) {

            bubblesArray.add(new Bubbles(bubblesArray.get(j).getPosXBubbles(), bubblesArray.get(j).getPosYBubbles(), bubble));

          }

          bubblesArray.remove(j);

        } else {

          bubbleWidth = 100 ;
          bubbleHeight = 100 ;
          bubble.resize(bubbleWidth, bubbleHeight);

          numberOfBubble=1;


        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Note that `Java` !== `JavaScript`

Comment: Try `bubble[j].resize(bubbleWidth, bubbleHeight)`

Comment: This wont work because iam working with arraylist